# ES6/When.js - Handling promise resolution in recursive promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise chain that is recursive i.e. calls itself until a value equals zero. This is working great however when it does finally resolve, the output is appended with "undefined" values, presumably one for each of the promise calls that are not resolved.

**QUESTION**: Can anyone advise on a best practice to handle expected unresolved values?

Options I can think of:

1) Handle these in the result set i.e. remove the undefined values e.g.

```
_.compact(response)
```

This does not feel like the right option but may be?

2) Throw an exception to be handled by the catch.

Appreciate any thoughts - code skeleton to help illustrate the issue below.

```
const queueTask = function queueTask(task) {
    ...
    }).then(response => {


        if (_.has(task, 'another')) {

            let taskConfigs = doSomething(task);

            //Add new tasks to queue. Return a promise that will resolve
            //only once all the items in array have resolved.
            return when.all(taskConfigs.map(function(each) {
                return queueTask(each);
            }));
        }

        if (task.remainingTasks === 0) {
            return response;
        } 



    }).catch(function (err) {
        ....
};
```

Comment: That's the expected output. Either do it another way (don't queue up tasks) or come up with an implementation of the promise pattern that doesn't do this (and wouldn't be compliant with the ECMAScript 6 promise specification). You'll only need the last value in the resulting list. Why don't you just get that instead of `_.compact` if you are concerned about looping through the array?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - many thanks, this is really helpful. Im new to Promises so a second opinion on "this is expected" is great. It makes good sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @SergiuParaschiv this is expected behavior.

I resolved this by simply removing the "undefined" responses using underscores `_.compact` method.

Answer (score 0):

for starters, I am finding two issues with your code:

- what kind of response do you want when both conditions  `_.has(task, 'another')` and `task.remainingTasks === 0` are false, guessing that is the origin for your `undefined` values.
- you are returning `when.all` response directly which is an array, is that what you want?

I would modify your code to:

```
}).then(response => {


  if (_.has(task, 'another')) {
    let taskConfigs = doSomething(task);
    return when.all(taskConfigs.map(function(each) {
    return queueTask(each);
    })).then(resultArray => response); // or whatever kind of result you want to post.
  }
  return response;


}).catch(function (err) {
```